# Data structure equivalent to map ( in java ) for large datasets

Tags: java, directed-graph

Is there an already implemented data structure that I can use in order to assign to an object
(in my case an Edge), an integer? I am reading a graph from a file , 10 mil vertices , 60 mil edges and I assign to each edge , a cost , using a map ( costs.put(e,cost) ).

I create the costs map in this way :

```
costs = new HashMap<Edge,Integer>();
```

The exception that it gives is :

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.HashMap.resize(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.HashMap.addEntry(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.HashMap.put(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: I don't think I follow your question.  Can you elaborate what (and why) you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Are you looking for an alternative to `HashMap` that is more memory-efficient?

Comment: Yes, there is, and you are using it. Increase your heap size. If you want to implement super-memory-efficient data structures on your own, I suggest studying Lucene's implementation.

Comment: I wanted to know if there is a data structure that I can use such that it does the same thing like a map does. Assign to an object , an integer in my case.

Comment: If you want to cut memory costs, implement `comparable` and use a `TreeMap`

Comment: @JanDvorak Why would that be more memory-efficient? `TreeMap`'s nodes add more overhead than raw arrays in `HashMap`, and both rely on  `Map.Entry` instances.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik hash maps allocate a lot of unused space to be efficient. I don't think the larger nodes of a tree map counter that.

Comment: @JanDvorak That depends on the initial capacity and the load factor. If chosen to carefully match the problem, there is no overhead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`HashMap` is the correct data structure for a basic `Map`. The problem you are having is that the JVM is not being instructed to reserve enough space to keep the file contents in memory. Start the JVM with a `-Xmx` flag. For instance `-Xmx1G` parameter will allow it to use 1 Gigabyte of memory.

Comment: and -XX:MaxPermSize=1000m for increasing your permgen memory limit by 1000 MB.

Comment: @IqbalDjulfri Why would OP waste memory on PermGen?

Comment: Increasing the heap size is the right way forward.  In our product we use a custom cache implementation, which uses about 20 GB of heap space - and everything works fine (with the right JVM parameters)

Comment: @IqbalDjulfri you mean increasing _to_ and PermGen does not affect heap space

Comment: I'm sorry for causing unnecessary discussion and clearly it doesn't have anything to do with the question, but I just post it alongside Tim's answer about -Xmx since I remember clearly the first time I have memory problem with Java application and it was so hard to find these answers. thank you :)

Answer (score 6):

You've got 6e7 edges. A plain Object takes 24 bytes (64-bit HotSpot), so that's 1.44e9 bytes right there (1.5 GB). Now you introduce the most efficient map imaginable, adding only 6e7 references plus 6e7 `Integer` objects. That's another 2.4e8 bytes for the refs and 1.44e9 bytes for the `Integer`s: another 1.5 GB, the total being now 3 GB—and this is the **theoretical lower bound** for your problem (modulo caching, see below).

Based on this I suggest you just extend your `Edge` class with another `int` field. This will drastically reduce your memory footprint.

If this is not an option, however, and:

- all your integers rarely exceed two digits,
- you are careful never to use `new Integer`, but `Integer.valueOf`, autoboxing, etc.,
- you use Java 7,

you'll automatically benefit from the built-in small integer cache. If the integers assume values from a wider range, but still with lot of duplication, a custom cache is highly advisable.

Comment: "A plain Object takes 24 bytes". Please specify on what JVM & architecture.

Answer (score 3):

Additionally to changing the jvms memory settings you can tweak `HashMap`s memory management with initial capacity and load balance.

Javadoc excerpt:

> An instance of HashMap has two parameters that affect its performance:
>   initial capacity and load factor. The capacity is the number of
>   buckets in the hash table, and the initial capacity is simply the
>   capacity at the time the hash table is created. The load factor is a
>   measure of how full the hash table is allowed to get before its
>   capacity is automatically increased. When the number of entries in the
>   hash table exceeds the product of the load factor and the current
>   capacity, the hash table is rehashed (that is, internal data
>   structures are rebuilt) so that the hash table has approximately twice
>   the number of buckets.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of creating a `HashMap`

```
costs = new HashMap<Edge,Integer>();
```

You can store cost within `Edge` object.

```
class Edge
{
    Vertex a;
    Vertex b;
    int cost;
}
```

This way you can save some memory in system.

Comment: Yes , but in this case I have to modify a lot of code in my program.

Comment: I believe you should modify design before implementation. It makes product more scaleable and maintainable.

Comment: @RaduStejerean, Map is an interface. Implement a custom Map whose `get(Edge key) { return key.cost; }`

Comment: I extended the heap size by using "-Xmx1G" in the arguments for run configurations , and it seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

Back to the original problem: You have Edges, that have costs. As your graph is sparse, why not use a sparse matrix? Maybe a Object-to-Integer mapping isn't what you really need and want.
You can look at apache.commons.math, i think they have sparse matrices. Also, you need to think about how you access the costs in your algorithms, to choose the proper sparse format (column based run-length encoding / row based rle or something else). Or you don't care, and use any, but then you should convert the thing in the beginning of your algorithms.

Comment: I guess the solution to this problem is a clever (math) way how to calculate cost instead of throwing memory at it. +1

Answer (score 1):

You do realize that this takes a **whole lot** of RAM, do you? Try [increasing the heap size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565388/increase-heap-size-in-java), and you'll be fine...

And to answer your original question: yes, that is what [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)s are for...

Answer (score 1):

You must specify per project how much heap space your project wants

I think you could follow this step:

```
Right mouse click - Run As - Run Configuration - Arguments - Vm Arguments, then add this -Xmx2048m
```

Comment: I have tried that , but it didn't work. Gave me the same exception.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps what you are looking for is [TObjectIntHashMap](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/javadocs/gnu/trove/map/hash/TObjectIntHashMap.html)  This is similar to `HashMap<Edge, Integer>` except it stores the `int` as a primitive potentially saving you some memory.  This collection can also be marginally faster when the collection is larger (as it fits into cache better)

```
TObjectIntHashMap<Edge> costs = new TObjectIntHashMap<Edge>();

costs.put(e, cost); // cost is stored as a primitive not its wrapper object.
```

Comment: Thanks , but I managed to increase the heap size and I am not going to change the data structure . At least for now.